# What fields need to be included when configuring IIS web logging according to PCI compliance regulations?

Tags: security, iis, log-files, pci-dss

From what little I know about PCI compliance I need to be logging all web site activity and keeping said logs online for at least 3 months.  What I have not been able to get a straight answer on, however, is what fields or properties must be included from the Advanced tab in IIS Logging properties.  Some seem obvious and need to be included (e.g. date,time,client IP) but others are not so obvious.

Here is this list of available fields (defaults in bold):

- **Date**
- **Time**
- **Client IP Address**
- **User Name**
- Service Name
- Server Name
- **Server IP Address**
- **Server Port**
- **Method**
- **URI Stem**
- **URI Query**
- **Protocol Status**
- **Protocol Substatus**
- **Win32 Status**
- Bytes Sent
- Bytes Received
- Time Taken
- Protocol Version
- Host
- **User Agent**
- Cookie
- Referer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones in bold above are all that are needed for PCI compliance.  Basically time/date/what they visited/details about them/respond information.

However, I would enabled all of them except for Cookie and Protocol.  Cookie can have cardholder data, so don't add it.

Time taken, bytes, host, referer are all useful columns that you will likely find useful.  Log files can be compressed well so it doesn't hurt to have extra data for when you need it.